# Tin can api (xAPI) launch not working

Tags: tin-can-api, lrs

I have a xAPI course created in Storyline which I'm trying to launch in the browser. After referring to the documentation on the internet I performed following steps:

1) Configured the Learning locker LRS locally.

2) Created the launch URL with the LRS end point, key and secret details.

**Launch URL:**

```
http://xapi.local.lcl/launcher.html?endpoint=http://192.168.168.66/data/xAPI/%26auth=Basic%20YWMwMWQ1NzliNmUzMWZlYzUwYTE3ZTI1NzBjMzI2ZmEwMjhjZTJkMjpjNzUzMGUwZTJjYjVjYWJmODFkOTYwZDIyODFhYTI5ZmZlN2EzYjAx%26actor%3D%7B%22objectType%22%3A%22Agent%22%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%5B%22Test%20User%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mainto%3Atet%40user.com%22%5D%7D%26registration%3D4b12bc8c-5347-46fa-99f3-e7bb91970c8%26activity_id%3Dhttp://5hJJBo0Cl3j_course_id
```

But when I opened the launch URL it's giving me following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asVersion' of null
    at TinCan.LRS.retrieveState (app.min.js:13)
    at TinCan.getState (app.min.js:13)
    at Object.getItem (app.min.js:14)
    at Object.initResumeData (app.min.js:18)
    at Object.initialize (app.min.js:18)
    at Array.O (app.min.js:45)
    at h (app.min.js:8)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.min.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.min.js:8)
    at h (app.min.js:8)
```

I'm new to xAPI so don't know how to proceed. I googled but couldn't find any approriate solution for the issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The launch URL you pasted appears to be incorrectly encoded. The `%26` at the end of the endpoint should be a literal `&`, so that the next query parameter, `auth` is separated. This is the case on through `actor` which is what I'm guessing is giving the `null` reference error when Storyline (and the underlying library, TinCanJS) is trying to serialize the Agent when making the xAPI State retrieve request.